# How to detect who viewed my Telegram profile?

Tags: telegram

Is there any event in telegram **API Bot** or **Core** to detect who is viewed a user or channel or group or bot profile?

*Some Bots and Apps claim that they can do this but i didn't find any programming way in the telegram API documents.*

For example I just see `getUserProfilePhotos` method in *Telegram Bot API* about user profile.

Also Update objects has the following items now (in Telegram Bot):

- update_id
- message
- edited_message
- channel_post
- edited_channel_post
- inline_query
- chosen_inline_result
- callback_query
- shipping_query
- pre_checkout_query

Answer (score 7):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869102/how-to-know-who-checks-my-telegram-profile/45897322#45897322), there is one way for doing that. In case you have an un-official fork of telegram (like Mobogram), everytime `user1` get's `user2`'s profile, you can store this get request and later inform `user2` that `user1` visited your profile. But in this case, both of the users must be using your fork. Telegram is so concerned about user's privacy so I don't think there will ever be a method in it's API for such purpose.

Answer (score 3):

No method to get this data at this time.

Telegram very care about privacy, so there is no way to track users.